# What is the MIME type of .eml files in emails

Tags: php, email, mime-types, mta

I want to attach a MTA report (not delivered bounce mail) to an email, but what is the correct MIME type?

I fetch the full body of the MTA report with

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($this->Mailbox->stream, $this->header->uid, '', FT_UID);
```

But what is the correct MIME type for attached .eml files?

Have tried `message/rfc822` but when you open the file in Thunderbird the popup windows is empty. Have also tried `text/plain` but then the attachment is opended as plain text. I want to open the attachment .eml as an email

When you receive a MTA report (not delivered) the bounce mail is always forwarded as an attachment

I want to attach the full MTA report + forwarded bounce mail to a new mail

Comment: Our (proprietary) mail client at work just sets `Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
name="xxx.EML" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxx.EML"`, and is able to open the received attachment “as” an email again via double click, though I could not say whether that was not probably due to the registered file ending. What happens when you send yourself a mail in Thunderbird, that you just attached an EML file to - does it work as desired then? If so, check the source code of that mail.

Comment: @CBroe its seems to work with `application/octet-stream` create an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Content-Type: application/octet-stream` should do the trick.

---

Our (proprietary) mail client at work just sets `Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="xxx.EML" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxx.EML"`, and is able to open the received attachment “as” an email again via double click. Since that mime type is anything but specific, I suppose it falls back onto the file type handler registered for the `.eml` suffix on the OS level.

Comment: This doesn't work for Gmail. When you receive an email with an `eml` attachment of type `application/octet-stream`, Gmail's web interface refuses to load it.

Answer (score 9):

`message/rfc822` ("[encapsulated message](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_3_Message.html)") works, at least with ReactDropzone.  That string is what's reported as Type when an .eml file is dropped.  (YMMV.)

Comment: That's also what the CLI tool `mimetype /path/to/file` tells me

Comment: I wish this is the selected answer. Email clients are just too flexible on this. `application/octet-stream` is for a generic file with bytes.

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no mime type for it based on list as of 2020-12-23. See:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml